# Set i = 1: end of file

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to have MATLAB read in a list of files. However, I have several lists of these files and they are all different lengths. How can I set a `for` loop so that the `i` goes from 1 to the end of the file? (The line I'm talking about is the 'for i = 1:END OF FILE' part.

To illustrate, the first few lines of my .dat file looks like this:

```
2006-01-003-0010.mat
2006-01-027-0001.mat
2006-01-033-1002.mat
2006-01-051-0001.mat
2006-01-055-0011.mat
```

My code looks like this:

```
for y = 1:9
flist = fopen([num2str(year(y))'_MDA8_mat.dat']); % Open the list of file names - CSV files of states with data under consideration
nt = 0; % Counter will go up one for each file loaded
while ~feof(flist) % While end of file has not been reached
    for i = 1:END OF FILE % Number of files CHECK EACH TIME FILE IS MODIFIED
        fname = fgetl(flist); % Reads next line of list, which is the name of the next data file
        disp(fname); % Stores name as string in fname
        nt = nt+1; % Time index

        load (fname, 'site_data'); % Load current file. It is all the data for one site for one year

        O3_data{i} = site_data;
    % Stuff
    end
end
```

Comment: First, try avoid using i as iterative variable in matlab. I is imaginary number normaly. In your While eof, you're already looping in your file so just read line by line until the end of this while. And when you're reading a line it suppose to be a new file name ? So just start another fopen and read it.

Comment: Matlab [fgetl](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) provide what you need and you have a little example how to loop in a file.

Comment: I need to loop through things in the file itself. `y` just loops through each `.dat` file, but each `.dat` file has a long list of files. I can use something other than `i`, but is there any way of specifying `for i = 1:something` when `something` is determined by how long the file is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
for y = 1:9

    flist = fopen([num2str(year(y))'_MDA8_mat.dat']); % Open the list of file names - CSV files of states with data under consideration

    while ~feof(flist) % While end of file has not been reached
        newFileName = fgetl(flist);

        fid = fopen(newFileName);
        while ~feof(fid)
            currentLine = fgetl(fid);
            % Do stuff on each sub-file
        end 
        fclose(fid);
    end
    flcose(flist);
end
```

There another while check you can do like this :

```
flist = fopen([num2str(year(y))'_MDA8_mat.dat']);
line = fgetl(flist);

while(ischar(line))
   %Do process (like open next file with the line variable)

   %read the next line
   line = fgetl(flist);
end
```

Comment: Do I need to have two counters (the `nt = nt + 1;`) for the two loops?

Comment: No, Sorry, I copy your code and didn't erase that. And into the second while just do fgetl(fid) to read what is in the current file.